# How to return T type or null in a method?

Tags: c#, null, nullable

I need a method that returns a class with unspecified type or null.

I need this to handle API requests like, I'm requesting a file, let's say an image and an other file like  a video and I need different types for that. If the image / video is not found, I want to return null.

I've already tried Nullables but I'm probably doing it the wrong way.

```
T? SendRequest<T?>(string pathOnServer)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = SendTheRequest(pathOnServer);
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple.

You just need to *limit the method* to what you say it should return.

> returns a class with unspecified type or null.

That is `T SendReuest<T> (string pathOnServer) where T : class`

As *classes automatically can be nullable* that is all that is needed. You just need to *limit **T** to be a **CLASS*** - not anything.

Comment: `default(T)` is way better, doesn't require constraints

Comment: But it also does not limit it to class and that is specifically asked for in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to constraint T as struct or class. You can try

```
return default;
```

This will return null if T is string or any reference types.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use `where T : class`

```
T SendRequest<T>(string pathOnServer) where T : class
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = SendTheRequest(pathOnServer);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            else
                return null;
        }
```